# Is this the right way to preload images?

Tags: javascript, html

Is this below the right way to preload images?

I have a table which changes background once a 'select option' is changed.
In the body of my page, I have this:

```
 <body onload="preload();">
```

And in my Form on the same page I have:

```
 <select onchange="swap();"><option bla bla></select>
```

And the js:

```
 function preload(){
 pic = new image(720, 65);
 pic.src = '../picture.jpg';
 }
 function swap(){
 document.getElementById("table_id_here").style.backgroundImage = '../picture.jpg';
 }
```

In the function swap() I guess the picture.jpg file is already preloaded, is that right?

Is there any way to check if the image has actually been cached (preloaded)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like Firebug's network tool to check if those images are loaded.

[image: Fiebug]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/net.gif))</sub>

I guess your codes should work, anyway this is a popular script used by Dreamweaver for image preloading:

```
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

MM_preloadImages('img1.gif','img2.gif'); //add more if required
```

Answer (score 3):

Load the image with CSS either by using a sprite or by using display:none to hide it. A bit less to do on the js front then.

Answer (score 0):

The word "image" should be capitalized in the second line of your `preload` function, like this:

```
pic = new Image(720, 65);
```

Remember that you're creating a new Image object by calling its constructor -- that's what loads it in the browser.

So if it's not capitalized, you're invoking a separate function that may or may not exist.